# PromQL: Access metric for instance while grouping by instance

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

Is there a way to access the current instance while grouping by instance. What I am trying to do is to get the kube_node_status_capacity_cpu_cores while grouping over instance.

At the moment I am hardcoding the amount of cpu cores, but I want to parametrize it, since the nodes might have different amounts of cores.

My promQL query now:

```
(1 - (avg by (instance) (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[15s])))) * 0.007 + 0.23) * 165 * 1.125 * 4)
```

where 4 is the number of CPUs. What I want now is something like

```
(1 - (avg by (instance) (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[15s])))) * 0.007 + 0.23) * 165 * 1.125 * kube_node_status_capacity_cpu_cores{instance=currentInstance})
```

Thank you for your help

**Edit**

I now know why the approach using on(instance) does not work. The instance label on the left is the ip of the node exporter providing the cpu time. The instance on the right is the ip of the kube-state-metrics pod.

What I actually need is to somehow map node from the state metrics onto the node name of the node export exporter in question. Any ideas?

**Edit 2**

In my specific case I was looking for a different query. But the accepted answer is actually very helpful for future reference, since it would have answered the question correctly, if I described the case correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `on()` operator:

```
sum by(instance) (metric1) * on(instance) metric2 * 0.007 + 0.23
```

And it will work if there is only one `metric2` with matching `instance`. Otherwise you need to apply some aggregation to `metric2` (like use `sum()`, `avg()`, etc) or maybe filter out irrelevant time series (`metric2{foo="bar"}`). More on one-to-one vector matches in the [docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#one-to-one-vector-matches).

Comment: I get the following error: found duplicate series for the match group {instance="ip"} on the right hand-side of the operation: [{__name__="my_metric", instance="ip", job="kubernetes-service-endpoints", kubernetes_name="kube-state-metrics", kubernetes_namespace="XXX", name="kube-state-metrics", node="XXX-00"}, {__name__="my_metric", instance="ip", job="kubernetes-service-endpoints", kubernetes_name="kube-state-metrics", kubernetes_namespace="XXX", name="kube-state-metrics", node="XXX-01"}];many-to-many matching not allowed: matching labels must be unique on one side

Comment: This makes sense, as I have multiple nodes on both ends. I now want to match them by their node name which is unique

Comment: @msts1906 You can do both instance and node: `by(instance, node)`, `on(instance, node)` and so on.

Comment: the query does not fail, but it is empty. It also does not fail if I say by(instance), on(node), but it remains empty

Comment: @msts1906 hold on, this doesn't make sense. You are getting `1 - sum(rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode"idle"})) by (instance)` which is average cpu usage per instance. Then you want to multiply it by the number or cores. Is that correct? If so, replace `avg` with `sum` and there is no need to use cores.

Comment: It is a little bit different, since my use case is very specific, but you gave me the right idea thank you! I was querying the wrong thing